# Angular 4 Lazy Loading Child Components Not Loaded

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have a medium size Angular App. Which is taking quite a lot of time in loading. Thus I decided to use Lazy Loading. I have a `FeedbackModule` which is lazy loaded. It looks like this:

Feedback Route:

```
export const FEEDBACK_ROUTES: Routes = [

{ path : '' , component : FeedbackComponent},
{ path : 'prebilling' , component : PrebillingComponent},
{ path : 'postbilling/login' , component : PostbillingComponentLogin},
{ path : 'postbilling/rating/:mid/:return/:mtid' , component : PostbillingRatingComponent},
{ path : 'prebilling/rating/:mid/:type/:mtid/:mcnt/:mebid' , component : PrebillingRatingComponent},
{ path : 'prebilling/rating' , component : PrebillingRatingComponent},
{ path : 'postbilling/rating/:id' , component : PostbillingRatingComponent},
{ path : 'prebilling/rating/:mid/:type/:mtid' , component : PrebillingRatingComponent},
{ path : 'thanks/:id' , component : ThankYouComponent}
];
```

Feedback Module:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    PostbillingComponentLogin,
    PrebillingComponent,
    PrebillingRatingComponent,
    PostbillingRatingComponent,
    ThankYouComponent,
    FeedbackComponent,
    PostbillingForgotPassComponentLogin

],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CommonCustomModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(FEEDBACK_ROUTES)
],
exports:[ RouterModule]
})

export class FeedbackModule {
}
```

App.route.ts:

```
export const ROUTES : Routes = [
...COMMON_ROUTES,
{ path:'feedback', loadChildren: './feedBack/feedback.module#FeedbackModule'}
]
```

Now when I got for path `/feedback` Feedback component is loaded. But when I for `/feedback/prebilling` or any other path it still loads FeedbackComponent. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try using the pathMatch: full option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems ok to me but you may try adding pathMatch: full

```
{ path : '' , component : FeedbackComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not targeting other routes as a child route of your lazy loaded module

const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: OrgComponent,
    children: [
{ path: 'intro', loadChildren: '../+intro/intro.module#IntroModule' },
{ path: 'recent', component: RecentComponent },
    ]
  }
]

[image]